# How do I simplify this expression to a single logarithm involving two -log?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

I have to find x in this equation. This is my first time encountering an expression with two -logs so I don't know which one goes in the denominator. The expression is:

$$\log_7(x+6) - \log_7(x-9) - \log_7(4) = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$\log_7(a) - \log_7(b)=\log_7\left(\frac ab\right)$

Comment: will this result to a complex fraction since there are two -log?

Comment: @Yeol $\log(a/b) - \log(c)$ can be simplified using the same rule.

Comment: will it be log((a/b)/c)?

Comment: @Yeol Yes. Now simplify the expression and you are done.